# Python 2.7 code to query out attribute data downloaded from external url

Tags: python, csv

I'm importing a csv from a few external sites and extracting the needed fields then creating a single combined csv file. However, there is some attribute data I need to eliminate either when I am importing the raw data or from the combined file.

I've found information regarding eliminating field but not specific attributes, and I am not running this through a database. I've tried an if else statement unsuccessfully, both in the writing section and reading section.

Here is where I am trying it during importing the data....

## National Section

```
    lg_fire_natl = r'D:\projects\lg_fire_canada\output\data\working\ca_natl_intermediate.csv'
    with open(lg_fire_natl, 'rb') as f:
        canada_vals = list(list(rec) for rec in csv.reader(f, delimiter=','))
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        for row in reader:
            if [6] == 'ak':
                pass
            else:
                ascii_canada.append(canada_vals)

    with open(lg_fire_natl, "wb") as natl_output:
        writer = csv.writer(natl_output)
        for val in canada_vals:
            writer.writerow(val)
```

Snippet from data import....
provinces = [{'abbr': 'natl', 'extension': 'csv', 'url': .......'fields': [6,1,3,5,4]},{'abbr': 'nwt', 'extension': 'csv', 'url': '

Field [6] pulls the abbreviated province name, however this Canada data includes attribuetes 'ak' (Alaska) and we do not want to include those data.

Thanks!!!!

Comment: For anyone with the same issue - Problem solved!!  I made two errors. 1)  I was not pointing to my list. It should read "for row in canada_vals:" and 2) I needed to point to the first item in my list which is [0] .

Comment: UPDATE CORRECTION TO SOLVED - Prior post resulted in removing AK data via print statement in cmd line, but not in output csv. ..I needed to move the statement to the writing portion...NOT the reading portion. Hope this helps someone!!
    
    with open(lg_fire_data[0], 'r') as first:
        combined.write(first.read())

    for i in range(1, len(lg_fire_data)):
        with open(lg_fire_data[i], 'r') as canada_vals:
            
            next(canada_vals, None)
            for val in canada_vals:
                if val[0] <> 'AK':
                    combined.write(val)